# Error:(17, 0) SDK location not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

So I got this error when trying to run Gradle in Android Studio. Except the problem is that the `local.properties` file already exists and contains the correct data. Also I have other projects on my computer with the exact same `local.properties` content and they work fine. I am getting this error for a sample that I download off Github. [Here is the link to the sample](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button).

Full Error:

> Error:(17, 0) SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in
>   the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment
>   variable. Open
>   File

To run the sample I just go to Android Studio: File > New > Import Project

Comment: Did you check at Project Settings if your Android SDK path is correctly set?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Same as in the local.properties file

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go to this-> File -> Project Settings, and [set SDK path as in Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF4Tg.png)